# compare a dictionary to itself but avoiding the comparison of a key twice if already compared

Tags: python, bioinformatics

Please I need help again.

I have a file named `vf_to_cluster.txt` that look like:

[image: simplified screenshot of my file]
From it I made a dictionary called `vf_accession_to_cluster_groups` where keys are `vf_accession` (AI0...) and values are the list of cluster groups (`['1','2','3'...]`).
 I've done that by coding this way (I know it's not a pretty code but that what I can do right now with what I know sorry):

```
f = 'script_folder/vf_to_cluster.txt'
vf_accession_to_cluster_groups = {}

with open(f, 'r') as f6:
    for lines in f6.readlines():
        lines = lines.replace('[', '')
        lines = lines.replace(']', '')
        lines = lines.replace(',', '')
        lines_split = lines.strip().split(' ')
        vf_keys = lines_split[0]
        cluster_values = lines_split[1:]
        vf_accession_to_cluster_groups[vf_keys] = cluster_values
```

After getting this dictionary my main objectif is to see how many `vf_accessions` (AI0...) share same cluster groups. So I can say for example that AI001 and AI002 share 4 cluster groups meaning that those two `vf_accession` are probably the same or really close (coded by same genes).
I made this code:

```
for vf_1 in vf_accession_to_cluster_groups.keys():
    print '-'*40
    for vf_2 in (vf_accession_to_cluster_groups.keys():
        res = 0 
        if vf_1 != vf_2:
            for i in vf_accession_to_cluster_groups[vf_1]:
                for j in vf_accession_to_cluster_groups[vf_2]:
                    if i == j : 
                        res = res + 1

            print vf_1, vf_2, res
```

I obtained something like that:
[image: output of my code in form of matrix-ish]

I managed to discard comparison like that: AI001 AI001 or AI002 AI002...
 by using `if vf_1 != vf_2`:

But I can't manage to not allow comparison like that:
AI014 AI015 then just after, my code compares them in another way AI015 AI014
so basically, what I want is to discard that type of comparison. If compared once don't compare it again in the other way. Can anyone help me please?

Also if any bioinformaticians sees my matrix-ish do you think that I should include the size of the list of cluster to my `vf_accession` comparison like doing:

```
dist = float(res) / len(set(vf_accession_to_cluster_groups[vf_1] + vf_accession_to_cluster_groups[vf_2]))
```

Thank you all for any help provided.

Comment: Why not use a set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have millions of keys, you could just store the keys in a list and sort them (makes the results human readable).

```
cluster_groups = list(vf_accession_to_cluster_groups.keys())
cluster_groups.sort()
```

Now you can use `enumerate` to loop over all the keys (except for the last one because you don't need to compare it to itself):

```
for index, vf_1 in enumerate(cluster_groups[:-1]):
```

and for the comparison loop over all the keys after the one you were just using for your outer loop

```
    for vf_2 in cluster_groups[index + 1:]:
```

**Complete code**

```
cluster_groups = list(vf_accession_to_cluster_groups.keys())
cluster_groups.sort()

for index, vf_1 in enumerate(cluster_groups[:-1]):
    print('-'*40)
    for vf_2 in cluster_groups[index + 1:]:
        res = 0 
        for i in vf_accession_to_cluster_groups[vf_1]:
            for j in vf_accession_to_cluster_groups[vf_2]:
                if i == j : 
                    res = res + 1

        print(vf_1, vf_2, res)
```

**Some small suggestions**

- Store the results in a dictionary so you can retrieve them later. You could use a dictionary of dictionaries.
- If you want to check if an item is in a list, just use

  `if item in my_list:`

**Updated code**

```
cluster_groups = list(vf_accession_to_cluster_groups.keys())
cluster_groups.sort()

results = dict()

for index, vf_1 in enumerate(cluster_groups[:-1]):
    print('-'*40)
    results[vf_1] = dict()
    for vf_2 in cluster_groups[index + 1:]:
        res = 0 
        for i in vf_accession_to_cluster_groups[vf_1]:
            if i in vf_accession_to_cluster_groups[vf_2]:
                res = res + 1

        print(vf_1, vf_2, res)
        results[vf_1].update({vf_2: res})


def get_results(key1, key2, results):
    if key1 > key2:
        key1, key2 = key2, key1

    if results.get(key1):
        return results[key1].get(key2)
    return None
```

Comment: Thank you very much for ur help. I really appreciate your clear explanation. I learned something new and valuable from ur code. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to get each pair only once.

In the following code, I define an `Accession` class to represent the information contained in a line of your file: The accession ID (`key` attribute) and the clusters (`clusters` attribute). The clusters are stored as sets, and this makes it easy to compute the number of clusters common between two accessions. This is implemented in the `nb_common` method, simply taking the length of the intersection (`&`) between the two sets. An `Accession` is created from each line in the file, thanks to the code present in the `__init__` method. The list of accessions is passed to the `combinations` function, with `2` as second argument, because we want pairs of accessions. We loop on the resulting pairs, and use the `nb_common` method to get the number of common clusters between the two accessions of the current pair.

Here I also used `sys.argv[1]` to get the file as first argument on the command line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from itertools import combinations

class Accession(object):
    """This represents an accession and the corresponding clusters."""
    def __init__(self, line):
        line_parts = line.strip().split(" ")
        self.key = line_parts[0]
        # "".join(...) re-creates a string representing the list of clusters
        # [1:-1] eliminates the brackets
        self.clusters = set("".join(line_parts[1:])[1:-1].split(","))

    def nb_common(self, other):
        return len(self.clusters & other.clusters)

with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as cluster_file:
    accessions = [Accession(line) for line in cluster_file]

for (acc1, acc2) in combinations(accessions, 2):
    print acc1.key, acc2.key, acc1.nb_common(acc2)
```

I call the script as follows:

```
$ ./compare_accessions.py vf_to_cluster.txt 
AI001 AI002 4
AI001 AI004 4
AI001 AI005 4
AI001 AI010 0
AI001 AI011 0
AI001 AI012 4
AI001 AI013 0
AI001 AI014 0
AI001 AI015 5
AI001 AI016 0
AI001 AI017 0
AI002 AI004 4
AI002 AI005 4
AI002 AI010 0
AI002 AI011 0
AI002 AI012 4
AI002 AI013 0
AI002 AI014 0
AI002 AI015 4
AI002 AI016 0
AI002 AI017 0
AI004 AI005 4
AI004 AI010 0
AI004 AI011 0
AI004 AI012 4
AI004 AI013 0
AI004 AI014 0
AI004 AI015 5
AI004 AI016 0
AI004 AI017 0
AI005 AI010 0
AI005 AI011 0
AI005 AI012 4
AI005 AI013 0
AI005 AI014 0
AI005 AI015 4
AI005 AI016 0
AI005 AI017 0
AI010 AI011 0
AI010 AI012 0
AI010 AI013 0
AI010 AI014 1
AI010 AI015 1
AI010 AI016 0
AI010 AI017 0
AI011 AI012 0
AI011 AI013 1
AI011 AI014 0
AI011 AI015 1
AI011 AI016 0
AI011 AI017 0
AI012 AI013 0
AI012 AI014 0
AI012 AI015 4
AI012 AI016 0
AI012 AI017 0
AI013 AI014 0
AI013 AI015 1
AI013 AI016 0
AI013 AI017 0
AI014 AI015 1
AI014 AI016 0
AI014 AI017 0
AI015 AI016 1
AI015 AI017 0
AI016 AI017 0
```

How to turn the number of common clusters into a distance seems quite an open question. You could ask this in the [bioinformatics stackexchange site](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/), not forgetting to introduce your biological questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for ur help. I also learned new stuff from ur code :D